# In a flask application, how can I redirect to a new page during ajax post based on condition discovered in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

In my flask application I have a sales page that collects information and saves it to the database via an ajax post request. There is a limited number of consoles available for users to record sales. A user can takeover a console from another user, but under this condition I want the initial user to lose access to the console. The console data retrieved in the view of the sales page has the information needed to determine this (available after each new sale).

I know I can’t do this with a standard “return redirect(url_for(‘dup_console’))” in the view because I’m posting through an ajax call.

I’ve spent a lot of time searching through SO and have found solutions that suggest performing the conditional logic in the success portion of the ajax call

Example:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.redirect) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
}
```

I’m not sure if this will work in my case as I can’t figure out how to get the console data from the view to the success routine. When I check the response information from the success routine it contains the html from the page.

Is there a way to get the information I need from the view to the success routine of the ajax post?

Here is a portion of my code (I've tried to reduce it to just the relevant pieces):

**View - sales_console**

```
@main.route('/sales_console/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def sales_console(id):
    product_data = get_product_data()
    console_data = get_console_data(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        returned_data = json.dumps(request.get_json())
        returned_data_dict = ast.literal_eval(returned_data)

        <review returned data and store in database>

        <retrieved data indicates if console id used by other device>
        if duplicate_console:
            redirect to page indicating console loss (I know I can’t do it like this)

return render_template('sales_console.html', product_data=product_data, console_data=console_data)
```

**Java Script routine available to sales_console.html template**

```
function record_sale(event,track_sales_data,console_number)
{
    var sales_data_json = JSON.stringify(track_sales_data);
    var url = "/sales_console/"+console_number;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : "POST",
        data: sales_data_json,
        contentType:"application/json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success!!!");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("failure!!!");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python, return whatever path you want to redirect on success as part of the json object you're returning, like this:

```
from flask import jsonify

# ...

if request.method == 'POST':
  # ...
  return jsonify(dict(redirect='path'))
```

In javascript, assign the returned path to the `location.href` property, to trigger the redirect. Like this:

```
// ...
success: function(response) {
  if (response.redirect) {
    window.location.href = response.redirect;
  }
}
```

Comment: Luis, I appreciate the clear and quick response. This worked perfectly for me. Thank you.

Comment: For me this worked as well, to add to your example I did: return jsonify(dict(redirect=url_for('page')))